# How to write a multiline "for" loop in the interactive PowerShell window?

Tags: powershell

I Googled a lot and someone said ` (backtick) can be used for line continuation but it does not work for me. I tried following but both would not work.

```
PS C:\> foreach ($i in 1,2) { echo $i; }
1
2
PS C:\> foreach ($i in 1,2) {
>> echo $i;
>> }
>>        <== It's still waiting for input. Killed with Ctrl-C.
PS C:\> foreach ($i in 1,2) { `
>> echo $i; `
>> }
>>        <== It's still waiting for input. Killed with Ctrl-C.
PS C:\>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you.

Comment: np - I remember Jeffrey Snover mentioning it as something tripping up a lot of people but I can't find the reference to it anymore.

Comment: Just as an aside if your code was less verbose would you need to use multiple lines? For example instead of `foreach ($i in 1,2) { echo $i; }` why not use `1..2 | % {$_}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use backticks  (or i  didnt have to)

but you do need to press enter a second time.

```
PS C:\> foreach ($i in 1,2) { echo $i; }
1
2
PS C:\> foreach ($i in 1,2) {
>> echo $i;
>> }
>>        <== Press enter again here.
1
2
PS C:\>
```

I presume this then lets the interpreter know that command has finished and allows it to execute.